# Multiply traiagular 2D matrices python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have an upper matrix "A" like following.

```
    1   2   3   4
1   0   1   3   0
2       0   3   1
3           0   3
4               0
```

Then there is another triangular matrix "B" as following

```
    1   2       3       4
1   0   14.89   23.89   0
2       0       24.39   14.89
3               0       23.89
4                       0
```

I need to multiply A[1,2] from B[1,2] , A[1,3], B[1,3]etc.

1 * 14.89

3 * 23.89

Code

```
In [14]: A = np.array([[0,1,3,0],[1,0,3,1],[3,3,0,3],[0,1,3,0]])

In [15]: A
Out[15]: 
array([[0, 1, 3, 0],
       [1, 0, 3, 1],
       [3, 3, 0, 3],
       [0, 1, 3, 0]])
In [16]: B = np.array([[0,14.89,23.89,0],[14.89,0,24.39,14.89],[23.89,24.39,0,23.89],[0,14.89,23.89,0]])

In [17]: B
Out[17]: 
array([[  0.  ,  14.89,  23.89,   0.  ],
       [ 14.89,   0.  ,  24.39,  14.89],
       [ 23.89,  24.39,   0.  ,  23.89],
       [  0.  ,  14.89,  23.89,   0.  ]])
```

This doest seems to be working. ?

```
for cell in np.triu(A).flat:
             for cell2 in np.triu(B).flat:
                 print cell*cell2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy array multiplication operates element-wise, so a simple `A*B` will suffice in this case.

For matrix dot, inner and outer products you need to use `numpy.dot`, `np.inner` and `numpy.outer` explicitly.

Comment: I was confused over this, using A*B solved my problem, Thanks.